# How to Get a Spock project running in Eclipse?

Tags: java, groovy, spock

I have tried twice to download the `examples.zip` file on the [Spock website](http://code.google.com/p/spock/). Each time I try to run `gradelw test` I get this exception:

`D:\tools\SPOCK-~1>gradlew test`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.BootstrapMain
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:36)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Wrapper.execute(Wrapper.java:58)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperMain.main(WrapperMain.java:39)
```

I don't see any mailing list. Is this tool being supported?

L

Comment: I would say it might be [supported here](http://groups.google.com/group/spockframework), That's all I can help you with.

Answer (score 3):

Install eclipse groovy plugin and then follow the [step by step tutorial here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2011/01/spocklight-add-spock-support-to-java.html)

Answer (score 0):

As daemon_x already said, the mailing list is here: http://forum.spockframework.org

As to your question, I haven't seen this error before, and I'd need more details (which version of spock-example, OS, etc.). How to get Spock running in Eclipse is a different question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  An old version that no longer works is on the webpage (.03 doesn't work).
I tried the .05 version and it worked.  Web Page needs to be updated. Ok n

Comment: May also need to delete .gradle folder and clean project. This might come in handy when one is banging their head against the wall, from non-nonsensical errors such as this.